# How to find actual hex value of color opacity in GIMP

Tags: gimp, transparency

I have a layer of color Red. It is a little transparent. I want to find actual RGBA value of it. The opacity is in percentage an I want the hex value of it. Is there any way, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a background layer or any layers underneath the colour you wish to sample, hide them in the layers panel by unchecking the Eye icon, so that you can see the transparency grid through the colour. You can unhide them later.

1. Do *Windows > Dockable dialogs > Sample points*
2. Hold down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and click and drag from the ruler to drop a sample point on the colour you wish to sample.
3. The RGBA values will be displayed in the Sample Points Panel.

Example

[image]

Convert the decimal numbers to hexadecimal using an online converter. For example the above sampled values would be #ff00006d

Comment: I am not used to using alpha values on hexadecimal notation. This is a good reminder that can be done.

Comment: @Rafael - yeah, I sometimes use the full RGBa hex code in Inkscape where you can [type it directly into the fill/stroke dialog](https://imgur.com/LzRLHvc).

Comment: @Rafael and obviously in SVGs, where e.g: **style="fill:#ff00006d"** is valid.

Comment: Thank you, it helped me alot.

Answer (score 0):

Use the pointer dialog (Windows > Dockable dialog > Pointer). It will show you the pixel value (in many forms, RGBA, RGBA as percent.., HSV...) and with the hex notation, at the pointer position, for the active layer or for the whole image ("Sample merged" option).

[image]